# Building minimization optimization problem for 2nd-order elliptic PDE

Tags: optimization, pde, numerical-analysis, discretization, elliptic-pde

I am solving elliptic PDE problem, for which, Euler scheme looks as following: 
$$ \nabla [\gamma ( |\nabla u|^2) \nabla u] = 0,$$
where
$$\gamma(|\nabla u|^2) = (1 + |\nabla u|^2)^{-1/2}. $$

I am aiming to define minimization problem for problem above. Does anybody have any suggestion how it should look like? Or some recommended literature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the particular equation you are solving (called the *minimal surface equation*), the functional you are trying to minimize is
$$
  J(u) = \int_\Omega \sqrt{1 + |\nabla u|^2} \; dx.
$$

You can find a derivation of the equations, as well as a discussion of solution approaches in lectures 31.5 and following here: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~bangerth/videos.html . Of course there are many other sources for the same material as well. For example, nearly every book about the calculus of variations will have your example.

Comment: is there any example, how to embedded framework into trust region framework ?

Comment: No. But I also don't quite understand: you have an unconstrained optimization problem. Why not just use a line search?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, that you have discretized problem and on every point you obtained 
evaluation $ g_{ij} $. Therefore $g(u) = 0$ is your system of nonlinear equations.

Now let $\gamma$ to be norm function defined as $\gamma(x) = || g(x)||^2$.

Then your nonlinear eq. problem is equivalent to the problem 
$$ \text{minimize} \ \  \gamma(x) .$$

Comment: This is not a useful approach because it yields degenerate optimization problems (that do not satisfy the second order sufficient conditions for optima) at places where $g(x)=0$ *and* $g'(x)=0$. You need to use a better approach.